# Yum dependency problems with packages installed from source

Tags: yum, packages, dependencies

I'm running CentOS 5.3 and this is my problem:

```
- I installed (A) from source. (B) depends on (A)
- I want to install the (B) RPM, but the (B) RPM depends on the (A) RPM.
```

So yum wants me to install the (A) RPM even though (A) is already installed. The reason I installed (A) from source is because I needed to use a newer version than what's avalable in repositories, and I also needed to configure it. What's a good way of resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a few ways:

1. Install the (B) RPM manually with the --nodeps option if you are sure the other dependencies are met.
2. Compile (A) into your own RPM. You can then install that and (B) will see that the dependency is met, and ensure future upgradeability [is that a word?].

Option 2. is preferable but will take longer to accomplish. Don't expect yum to add --nodeps support [anytime soon](http://lists.baseurl.org/pipermail/yum/2004-April/015395.html). :)

Comment: I would say option 2 is the only way to go: option 1 will only re-introduce the dependency problems again and again and again, ad nauseum.